# Can i make a connection to imap server using just angular (angular 5)?

Tags: angular, tcp, websocket, angular5, imap

I am trying to create an email application in angular. I don't want to have any backend or server side process for this. My idea is to do using IMAP. I see that the first step in this is to create an tcp connection between client and IMAP server(I guess imap uses only tcp connections)but i came to know that tcp connections are not possible through browsers(client based javascript). Am i correct on this or is it possible to make tcp connections through browser or in simple can i implement email using IMAP in pure angular 5?

Note- I see implementations of this using angular in frontend and nodejs/php in backend. That is not what i want. I want it purely in Angular.

Any information/lead on this is very much appreciated!

Comment: Too broad; [many other questions already have answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+tcp+connection) to part of this.

Comment: It would be great if you can share the links